# How to add a QMouseEvent to an EventFilter?

Tags: c++, qt, eventfilter

I added an EventFilter to a QCompleter because I had the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865129/8450121) person.

Now I want to add a left mouse button event if an item is clicked from the PopupCompletion.
I tried but I have no idea if I'm on the right track because im new to Qt.

### eventfilter.h

```
class EventFilter : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   EventFilter(QLineEdit* lineEdit, QObject* parent = NULL)
      :QObject(parent)
      ,mLineEdit(lineEdit)
   { }
   virtual ~EventFilter()
   { }

   bool eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event);

private:
   QLineEdit* mLineEdit;
};
```

### eventfilter.cpp

```
#include "eventfilter.h"

bool EventFilter::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    QAbstractItemView* view = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(watched);
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return ||
            keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter ||
            keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
        {
            mLineEdit->clear();
            mLineEdit->setFocus();
            view->hide();
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            mLineEdit->clear();
            mLineEdit->setFocus();
            view->hide();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### mainwindow.h

```
#include "eventfilter.h"

class QCompleter;
class QLabel;
class QLineEdit;
class QWidget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    void createMenu();
    QAbstractItemModel *modelFromFile(const QString& fileName);

    QCompleter *completer;
    QLabel *contentsLabel;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QWidget *widgetBox;
};
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

completer = new QCompleter(this);
completer->setModel(modelFromFile(":/resources/wordlist.txt"));
completer->setModelSorting(QCompleter::CaseInsensitivelySortedModel);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
EventFilter *filter = new EventFilter(lineEdit);
completer->popup()->installEventFilter(filter);
```

Comment: 1) there are NO `bool eventFilter` with signatire that you use. Use an override keyword to solve such errors. 2) Show a code, where you install your event filter. 3) read documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter

Comment: Your code is deemed to crash, as either `keyEvent` or `mouseEvent` will be `nullptr`. Just add a second `if` for the second event type. Also, I wouldn't use `dynamic_cast` in this situation, but normal `static_cast`